# Magento: where can I set some params/vars to "newsletter_subscr_success.html" email template?

Tags: magento, newsletter

I need to customize the "newsletter_subscr_success.html" email template and I need to pass some variables into it.

The problem is that I don't know where is it sent so I can push some parameters/variables.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any variables in controllers files or models or model/observer.php, which should be in the format,

```
$emailTemplateVariables['any_string'] = "This is any string";
```

Now, to grab this variable into your newsletter_subscr_success.html, just give

```
<div>{{var any_string}}</div>
```

and you are done!